# I need help selecting within a MySQL DateTime range in Java

Tags: java, mysql, datetime

I've got the following code in my app

```
String sql = "SELECT colA, colB, colC " + 
    "FROM " + tblName + " WHERE UserId = " + userId + 
    " AND InsertTimestamp BETWEEN " + lastDate + 
    " AND " + DataProcessor.TODAY + " ORDER BY UserId, Occurred";
try{
  if(null == conn)
    openDatabaseConnection();
  PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
  ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();  <------- this is the line which throws the SQL exception
  retArray = this.getArrayListFromResultSet(rs);
}catch(SQLException sqle){
  JSONObject parms = new JSONObject();
  eh.processSQLException(methodName, sqle, sql, parms);
}
```

So when I run my app in the debugger, I get  this exception message

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '00:00:00.0 AND 2014-08-20 00:00:00.0 ORDER BY UserId, Occurred' at line 1

I'm reasonably certain that there's simple and reasonable solution to this, but I have not been able to find it.

I've tried looking in the MySQL manual for a solution or a different format.

I've tried running my timestamps through a TIMESTAMP() functino and a DATE() function in the SQL, neither of which helped.

I pulled the fully formed SQL out of the Java code and ran it in MySQL Workbench with no issues, what-so-ever.  So now I'm looking to the experts for help.

Comment: http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: Yeah, I feel ya.  It's not the best coding practice and if this weren't a private method being passed specific and clearly defined parms from the calling method, you'd be dead on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dates in SQL must be enclosed within single quotes like strings.
As you're using a prepared statemtent, why you don't use '?' and stmt.setDate(...)?

```
String sql = "SELECT colA, colB, colC " + 
"FROM " + tblName + " WHERE UserId = ?" + 
" AND InsertTimestamp BETWEEN ?" + 
" AND ? ORDER BY UserId, Occurred";
try {
    if(null == conn) {
        openDatabaseConnection();
    }
    PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    stmt.setInt(1, userId);
    stmt.setDate(2, lastDate);
    stmt.setDate(3, DataProcessor.TODAY);
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();  
    retArray = this.getArrayListFromResultSet(rs);
} catch(SQLException sqle) {
    JSONObject parms = new JSONObject();
    eh.processSQLException(methodName, sqle, sql, parms);
}
```

Anyway, I think you are setting the dates in the opposite order. You should put first 'today' then lastDate. Although I don't know your constraints...

Comment: `stmt.setInteger(1, userId)` should probably be `stmt.setString(1, userId)`  (or `stmt.setInt(1, userId)`) instead.

Comment: Yes, or setLong or whatever, I didn't remember the syntax... changed!

Comment: Ok, anyway, you need to enclose the dates within single quotes, if not, you'll get that 'syntax error'

Comment: I failed to include the break in this code - as the complexity of the SQL and parameters being determined in one method and then passed to the database access object method which actually generates the PreparedStatement and then executes - as there are several db queries.  Consequently, I was building the entire query in the first method and passing to the called database access object method.  This may or may not have helped in getting solutions suggested.  I'll get better at asking these questions as time goes on.

Comment: I know this is what I should be doing, so I'm just trying to work out passing the parameters IN ORDER and without doing a lot of converting and manipulation of the data and allow the generic getResults() method to pull the values back.  I may end up just overriding that method and/or make it less generic.  Either way, this is the correct approach, I was just trying to get around it and it wasn't the right thing to do.

Comment: I ended up duplicating the database access object method, creating one to be specific to this situation and passing the parameters and setting them as suggested above.

Comment: I think it's the best choice. Having so generic methods may cause a lot of problems in the future. Hard to maintaing that code.